# How to prevent another service failure when one service fails to start in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

We have two services running in one Tomcat, e.g. svr1 and svr2

```
<Context path="/svr1" docBase="svr1" />
<Context path="/svr2" docBase="svr2" />
```

When Tomcat is started, svr1 fails due to incorrect configuration, then svr2 fails to start as well. How to prevent svr2 from failure when svr1 fails? In other words, how to ensure svr2 works well even if svr1 fails to start?

Answer (score 1):

It looks that the cause of your problem is that you placed your `<Context>` elements into the `server.xml` file. Doing so [is not recommended](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context).

The recommended practice is to rely on [deployOnStartup](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deployment_on_Tomcat_startup) feature (which is similar to how autoDeploy works, but `autoDeploy` is usually turned off on productive configurations). In this case additional configuration for a Context may go into a file named `conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/[appname].xml`, e.g. `conf/Catalina/localhost/srv1.xml`. Though in your case it looks like no additional configuration is needed.

Placing `<Context>` elements into the `server.xml` file bypasses the normal deployment mechanics. One consequence is that any startup failures of those web applications will result in Tomcat itself failing to start up.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following solution and it works:

1. Find the root cause where the svr1 exception occurs.
2. Catch the exception and gracefully handles it in svr1.

Thus, svr1 starts successfully although its `healthCheck` API gives unhealthy information. Meanwhile, svr2 and Tomcat will not be blocked by svr1 failure.